# How to parse it into a PHP object?

Tags: php, parsing

I'm trying to parse site data using PHP + curl. And that's what I saw in the debug window in chrome: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcJpL.png

Here is a server response below. How to parse it to PHP object?

```
Arr = new Array();

Arr[Arr.length] = new MeetingDetails();
Arr[Arr.length - 1].mode = 2;
Arr[Arr.length - 1].details = replaceLineBreakToHTML('');
Arr[Arr.length - 1].meetingTime =  CreateNewDateFromMiliInUTC(1432374300000);
var informationArr=new Array();
Arr[Arr.length - 1].cfInformationArr=informationArr;
Arr[Arr.length - 1].attendeeArray = new Array();
Arr[Arr.length - 1].attendeeArray[0] = new Array();
Arr[Arr.length - 1].attendeeArray[0][0] = htmlDecodeText('Sue',true);
Arr[Arr.length - 1].attendeeArray[0][1] = htmlDecodeTextWOlt('suew');

Arr[Arr.length] = new MeetingDetails();
Arr[Arr.length - 1].mode = 2;
Arr[Arr.length - 1].details = replaceLineBreakToHTML('');
Arr[Arr.length - 1].meetingTime =  CreateNewDateFromMiliInUTC(1431769500000);
var informationArr=new Array();
Arr[Arr.length - 1].cfInformationArr=informationArr;
Arr[Arr.length - 1].attendeeArray = new Array();
Arr[Arr.length - 1].attendeeArray[0] = new Array();
Arr[Arr.length - 1].attendeeArray[0][0] = htmlDecodeText('Tara ',true);
Arr[Arr.length - 1].attendeeArray[0][1] = htmlDecodeTextWOlt('suew');
```

Looks like a code, but how to make a PHP object from this?

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: These all are itself php array objects. what you want ? can you please put here what your desired output you want.

Comment: That looks like Javascript, with various function calls and other stuff... you cannot just parse it into PHP. Where are you getting it from, and why are you trying to convert it to PHP? It seems like an odd thing to do.

Comment: Please check the screenshot from the post. I get this response from the site which I'm trying to parse.

Comment: Simple replaces would make it a valid PHP code, but do you want that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
<?php
$data = file_get_contents('scheduleonce.txt');
$data = explode("\r\n", $data);
$arr = array();
$i = - 1;
foreach ($data as $string) {

    preg_match_all("#.title = htmlDecodeText\('(.*?)',true\);#i", $string, $matches);
    if (isset($matches[1][0])) {
        $i++;
        $arr[$i]['title'] = $matches[1][0];
    }

    preg_match_all("#.status = (.*?);#i", $string, $matches);
    if (isset($matches[1][0])) $arr[$i]['status'] = $matches[1][0];
}

print_r($arr);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do one thing, Use json encode and decode fujction.

First push array to json encode then push encode to decode.

$varObj = jason_decode( json_encode($arr)) ;

Comment: `jason_decode()`?! Also, the stuff in the question is **not** JSON...

Comment: This would work for a PHP array, but not whatever this is.